# How to express a certain sentence of english in regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a ASP.NET regular expression validator and how do I express:

> "If the value to be tested is empty or contains [a-zA-Z0-9\s]+ elements?"

in regex?

I have to test a TextBox in ASP.NET, and while submitting the request, I would want the regular expression validator attached to TextBox to allow submitting the form if it contains characters, numbers or is empty.

matched example 1. `"This is a good 1"`

matched example 2. `""`(empty)

unmatched example 1. `"what is this ****?"` (because it contains '*' and '?')

Comment: Um. What? What exactly are you trying to do? Get a regex that matches the above? If so, please explain what you tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: @Oded ok, let me clarify

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*` maybe???

Comment: Ok thanks let me just test it @leppie

Comment: Examples of inputs that should and should not match would be much more helpful.

Comment: @Oded done as per requirements :-)

Comment: Are you trying to say that you want users to be able to create their own validators and express them in English?

Comment: @Mark I wanted a regex that matches "a-z", "A-Z", "0-9", whitespaces and it **can** be blank.

Comment: I think @Leppie has it nailed.

Comment: @Aniket: Well, you were already 99% of the way there. Just change the `+` (match 1 or more) to a `*` (match 0 or more). You should brush up on what those symbols actually mean ;)

Comment: @Mark I was just not thinking simple :-)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one has actually posted it as an answer yet...

Just change the `+` to a `*` in your regex. The former means match 1 or more, whereas the latter matches 0 or more. This is what you want since you want to allow blanks.

Comment: I was about the delete the question actually. But let me just +1 and accept the answer. Thank you though :-)